# Comparison Graph in Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I want to create graph as a template which will give me comparison of the current data with the old data . The data will be pushed once in every 24 hours and I want create the comparison graph of current data and the one 24 hrs before.

Please help, I am not able to use the Date Range aggregation.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at Timelion, which does exactly what you need :

https://www.elastic.co/blog/timelion-timeline

Answer (score 0):

This is what i am trying to do

I have two set of data for two different Date range

October 21st 2016, 11:30:00.000 to October 21st 2016, 12:30:00.000

October 24th 2016, 15:30:00.000 to October 24th 2016, 16:30:00.000

The data is available between the time range

Now in the visualization i am using the below format

```
{
  "title": "comparision_jmeter_jenkins",
  "type": "line",
  "params": {
    "shareYAxis": true,
    "addTooltip": true,
    "addLegend": true,
    "showCircles": true,
    "smoothLines": false,
    "interpolate": "linear",
    "scale": "linear",
    "drawLinesBetweenPoints": true,
    "radiusRatio": 9,
    "times": [],
    "addTimeMarker": false,
    "defaultYExtents": false,
    "setYExtents": false,
    "yAxis": {}
  },
  "aggs": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "type": "count",
      "schema": "metric",
      "params": {}
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "type": "date_histogram",
      "schema": "segment",
      "params": {
        "field": "timestamp",
        "interval": "auto",
        "customInterval": "2h",
        "min_doc_count": 1,
        "extended_bounds": {}
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "3",
      "type": "date_range",
      "schema": "group",
      "params": {
        "field": "timestamp",
        "ranges": [
          {
            "from": "now-5d/d+6h",
            "to": "now-5d/d+7h"
          },
          {
            "from": "now-2d/d+10h",
            "to": "now-2d/d+11h"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
  "listeners": {}
}
```

Now I am not getting both the trends

[image]